# What tools (free) do you use to design software

Tags: architecture, uml

What tools do you use to speed up documenting application design.
Namely, creating wireframes, flowcharts. What other methods do you find essential .

Is the general consensus that use cases are vital, or is a good functional  spec document easier and quicker

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[ArgoUML](http://argouml.tigris.org/) has been my friend for many years when it comes to drawing UML. ArgoUML is a *tool* and you're asking about *both* tools and the *processes* used (i.e. "which artifacts do you create with the tools). We generally stick to user stories (agile project) and do not make "classical" use cases and use case documents.

Comment: Thanks, agree. Might need to do wireframes or something for the UI. Often the UI is nothing like I envisaged :)

Answer (score 9):

I use [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/) for UI design and [Visual Paradigm Aigilian](http://www.visual-paradigm.com/product/ag/) for modelling - it allows to nicely go from high-level business processes to granular requirements and UML modelling... And it's quite cheap.

Comment: Balsamiq looks like it is just what I need for UI mock ups

Comment: I use Balsamiq too, seems a nice little app. It has the added benefit of allowing you to show people your designs without them thinking its a finished thing which is allowed by the "sketched" appearance of controls.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice the 'free' word. But I think I gave you pointers to two great tools - if not for now, then maybe for the future. Good luck :)

Comment: Oh my, that balsamiq is just what I've been looking for!

Comment: Balsamiq is AWESOME. I've bought a license, as I do with all tools I think are awesome ;-)

Answer (score 8):

The [pencil](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/8487) add-on for Firefox is pretty good for simple diagrams and GUI sketches.

And if you don't like it as a FF add-on, you can download a [standalone version](http://www.evolus.vn/Pencil/Downloads.html) for Linux or windows.

Comment: This is just brilliant !...I've looking for a long time for something like that !

Answer (score 8):

[Sparx EA](http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/products/ea/index.html) is big bang for the buck.  Multi language support with roundtripping and team support.  Been using it for three years without complaint.

I've used Rational Rose, Poseidon, ArgoUML, and several free Eclipse plugins.  Rational's too big and slow, Poseidon was great (free version imprints semi-nude greek god of the sea on your diagrams), and Argo always gave me problems and didn't diagram what I need.  I never found a good "free" Eclipse plugin... was always waiting for that magic bullet.

Comment: it is not working good on linux OS

Answer (score 7):

I use [Freemind](http://freemind.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) to handle all the ideas i get when im brainstorming a the solution of a problem. And then by using the icons and colors on each node i can prioritize them. I really like that freeware tool.

Comment: Same here. Enjoy using Freemind

Answer (score 4):

Mostly Dia (http://projects.gnome.org/dia/), whiteboard and for quick "drawings" pen and paper.

Answer (score 3):

Paper and pencil, and whiteboard and dry erase marker. Later I transfer it to Visio once I've worked out the major problems. Unfortunately it doesn't meet your requirement of free, sorry.

Comment: how do you find visio? easy and quick?

Comment: "How do I find it?" - I just clicked on the Start button and there it was. Boom, boom, thanks for listening, I'm here all week :-)

Comment: ROFL!

You can find it (and a 60-day trial) here: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/visio/default.aspx

Comment: I find visio to be a bit much for software flowcharts.  Perhaps because it is made for many other types of applications (hardware diagrams etc.).  But i haven't used it in a serious way.

Answer (score 3):

I use a four-section whiteboard with embedded printer. That way, I can both do design privately at my desk or in a group of peers, and it lets me print out my ramblings for later on.

I've never found an application that gives me all those capabilities (although a 6 foot by 4 foot monitor would be neat, I don't think my employer will pony up the cash for it).

Sometimes the best technological solution is no technology at all (although I *will* be checking out the other answers to see if the tools have improved since the last time I looked - I'm pretty cynical however so I approach it with a certain pessimism).

Comment: I like this answer, I never find a better solution, initially than pen and paper, and it's the time spent putting this into electronic form that I hate to do :)

Comment: my todo list currently comprises of scraps of used printer paper ripped into 105 x 75mm (roughly) pieces. (rip An A4 sheet into half a few times). Each sheet has a step in whatever projects I'm working on. I can spread them out and get an overview, or re-order them to re-prioritise.

Answer (score 2):

OpenOffice.org's "Draw" does a decent job for creating flowcharts and similar diagrams, as long as you don't expect it to know (and enforce) the syntax and semantics of a given diagram type.

Answer (score 2):

dia, graphviz (dot), pen and paper, and my own mind.

All of these are free as in speech. Dia and graphviz are also free as in beer.

Answer (score 1):

[Gliffy](http://www.gliffy.com/examples) (wireframing, flowcharting) has a free basic version but all documents produced this way are public, therefore not very usable I guess.

Answer (score 1):

I usually find myself using MS Excel for drawing flowcharts rather than Visio because of its ease of use, and the juxtaposition of spreadsheet calculations with the flowchart itself. I write the pseudocode right next to the flowchart in MS Excel, and that makes reviewing much easier.

Comment: There's an open source equivalent of Visio called Dia ( http://projects.gnome.org/dia/ )

Answer (score 1):

Skectching paper (3' by 2') and a sharpie and pencil. I like the large surface, but find it easier to work on a horizontal surface (rather than using a whiteboard.)

I've actually modeled some flowcharts for the boss in MS Publisher. The drawing tools are good enough, and it converts to pdf. Not free, but may be on your workstation already.

I don't always do use cases, or even user stories, but will always brainstorm how a new app will be used, and by whom, before planning. That helps me better defend my specs.

Answer (score 1):

Here's more detail from [one of my posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952558/what-kinds-of-tools-do-you-use-for-conceptual-design-of-your-software).

Answer (score 1):

Visio mostly, drawboard/pen&paper for drafts. I write my final thoughts on a word processor and publish them for other team members to comment. presentations are also important to deliver your concept to a broad audience (important in large companies where many teams might be affected by your design/new system, and you want to get feedback from everyone).

I will be checking out the recommendations here though, maybe I'll find some new useful tool.

Answer (score 1):

Thats online tool from Autosketch also may be usefull for modeling aand designing.
http://draw.labs.autodesk.com/ADDraw/draw.html

Answer (score 0):

I am currently using [OmniGraffle](http://www.omnigroup.com/applications/omnigraffle/) for both sketching and documentation (combined with paper and pencil of course). It is quite elegant, fast and makes it easy to produce good looking documentation.

The major drawback is that it is not connected to the code at all, which makes refactoring a bit harder, but that goes for many of the tools right? It not free either, although quite cheap for a tool with it's maturity and strength.

Comment: This is only available for Mac or iOS

Answer (score 0):

I find Umbrello (bumped into it while bopping around KDE on Fedora) to be a nice tool, although I don't have much to compare it to.